# Is there a way to get sign post information from the here SDK navigate edition

Tags: here-api

Is there some way to get signpost information from the navigate here SDK?
For example, the color and shape of the exit sign during navigation.

Comment: Also is there an attribute to figure out if the road has tolls or other road features ? The route object in the SDK did not have any such data.

Comment: The features of providing signpost images are on the 2022 roadmap.
During Navigation, you can use add RoadAttributesListener to get the road attribute.
The following doc provides the guide of getting Toll Costs Along a Route.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-navigate/4.11.3.0/dev_guide/topics/routing.html#get-toll-costs-along-a-route

Answer (score 0):

The features of providing signpost images are on the 2022 roadmap. During Navigation, you can use add RoadAttributesListener to get the road attribute. The following doc provides the guide of getting Toll Costs Along a Route.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-navigate/4.11.3.0/dev_guide/topics/routing.html#get-toll-costs-along-a-route